# SQL query to find columns with more than one string "a href" in them

Tags: mysql, sql, string

I'm organizing articles in a big database and I face a problem - I need to find all articles with two or more links in them.

Every link is HTML link and has form `<a href="...">...</a>`. How do I `SELECT` from article database with all links that a have at least two `a href` in them?

I was taught how to select one `a href` but two?...

```
SELECT * FROM `Articles5` WHERE
content LIKE "%a href%"
```

How to double this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had you tried using your own code but twice?

```
SELECT * FROM `Articles5` WHERE
content LIKE "%a href%a href%"
```

Comment: It worked!! You=genius. I will accept your answer as soon as I can. In 1 hr.

Answer (score 0):

At first you can get all Articless WHERE content LIKE "%a href%" and put in temporary table. Then replace this value and find "a href" once more.

P.S For this purpose I advice you to use FullTextSearch